# Are some primes 'more prime' than others?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

Say a prime number $p$ is of order $k$ if $k$ is the smallest non negative number $f$ such that the $f$-th iterate of the prime counting function, denoted by $\pi^{(f)}$, verifies $\pi^{(f)}(p)$ is not itself prime. Hence $2$ has order $1$, $3$ has order $2$, $4$ has order $0$, and so on.

> Is there a way to take the order of a prime into account in sieve methods to get a better knowledge of the distribution of primes?

Comment: I think instead of "verifies" you mean "satisfies" or "has the property that". (a common French-to-English issue) To address the question you're asking though: why do you think there should be?

Comment: Simply because order $k'$ primes should be 'rarer' than order $k$ primes whenever $k'>k$ and thus have lower density. Counting primes of a given order may lead to more accurate results. And thanks for the English lesson by the way.